# Functional Programming - Implementing Scan (Prefix Sum) using Fold

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I've been teaching myself functional programming, and I'm currently writing different higher order functions using folds. I'm stuck implementing scan (also known as prefix sum). My map implementation using fold looks like:

```
(define (map op sequence)
  (fold-right (lambda (x l) (cons (op x) l)) nil sequence))
```

And my shot at scan looks like:

```
(define (scan sequence)
  (fold-left (lambda (x y) (append x (list (+ y (car (reverse x)))))) (list 0) sequence))
```

My observation being that the "x" is the resulting array so far, and "y" is the next element in the incoming list. This produces:

```
(scan (list 1 4 8 3 7 9)) -> (0 1 5 13 16 23 32)
```

But this looks pretty ugly, with the reversing of the resulting list going on inside the lambda. I'd much prefer to not do global operations on the resulting list, since my next attempt is to try and parallelize much of this (that's a different story, I'm looking at several CUDA papers).

Does anyone have a more elegant solution for scan?

BTW my implementation of fold-left and fold-right is:

```
(define (fold-left op initial sequence)
 (define (iter result rest)
  (if (null? rest)
   result
   (iter (op result (car rest)) (cdr rest))))
 (iter initial sequence))

(define (fold-right op initial sequence)
 (if (null? sequence)
  initial
  (op (car sequence) (fold-right op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho scan is very well expressible in terms of `fold`.

Haskell example:

```
scan func list = reverse $ foldl (\l e -> (func e (head l)) : l) [head list] (tail list)
```

Should translate into something like this

```
(define scan
  (lambda (func seq)
    (reverse 
      (fold-left 
       (lambda (l e) (cons (func e (car l)) l))
       (list (car seq))
       (cdr seq)))))
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn’t do this. `fold` can actually be implemented in terms of `scan` (last element of the scanned list). But `scan` and `fold` are in fact orthogonal operations. If you’ve read the CUDA papers you’ll notice that a scan consists of two phases: the first yields the fold result as a by-product. The second phase is only used for the scan (of course, this only counts for parallel implementations; a sequential implementation of `fold` is more efficient if it doesn’t rely on `scan` at all).

Comment: You're correct that this is not "the way to do it", but it is an interesting exercise, which is why I'm doing it. I did read the CUDA papers, and I won't try to actually use this in a real system. It's just a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

imho Dario cheated by using reverse since the exercise was about expressing in terms of fold not a reverse fold. This, of course, is a horrible way to express scan but it is a fun exercise of jamming a square peg into a round hole.

Here it is in haskell, I don't know lisp

```
let scan f list = foldl (\ xs next -> xs++[f (last xs) next]) [0] list
scan (+) [1, 4, 8, 3, 7, 9]
[0,1,5,13,16,23,32]
```

of course, using teh same trick as Dario one can get rid of that leading 0:

```
let scan f list = foldl (\ xs next -> xs++[f (last xs) next]) [head list] (tail list)
scan (+) [1, 4, 8, 3, 7, 9]
[1,5,13,16,23,32]
```

Comment: my bad, i guess I should read the question before commenting, though I can't read lisp, it looks like the asker already had this solution but didn't like it?

Comment: Yea, you see, this is a great solution except for the (last xs) since that's very non-functional! I'm starting to wonder whether this is something that can easily be done.