# How to get each value of inject loop

Tags: ruby

I want to get each value of `inject`.

For example `[1,2,3].inject(3){|sum, num| sum + num}` returns `9`, and I want to get all values of the loop.
I tryed `[1,2,3].inject(3).map{|sum, num| sum + num}`, but it didn't work.

The code I wrote is this, but I feel it's redundant.

```
a = [1,2,3]
result = []
a.inject(3) do |sum, num|
  v = sum + num
  result << v
  v
end

p result
# => [4, 6, 9]
```

Is there a way to use `inject` and `map` at same time?

Comment: What you are looking for is called the [prefix sum (or `scan`)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function), and [the implementation in terms of `fold`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2243812/2988) is not as trivial as one would hope. Unfortunately, `scan` is not part of the Ruby core libraries or standard libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dedicated `Eumerator` perfectly fits here, but I would show more generic approach for this:

```
[1,2,3].inject(map: [], sum: 3) do |acc, num|
  acc[:map] << (acc[:sum] += num)
  acc
end
#⇒ => {:map => [4, 6, 9], :sum => 9}
```

That way (using hash as accumulator) one might collect whatever she wants. *Sidenote*: better use `Enumerable#each_with_object` here instead of `inject`, because the former does not produce a new instance of an object on each subsequent iteration:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object(map: [], sum: 3) do |num, acc|
  acc[:map] << (acc[:sum] += num)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I could think

```
def partial_sums(arr, start = 0)
  sum = 0
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |elem, result|
    sum = elem + (result.empty? ? start : sum)
    result << sum
  end
end

partial_sums([1,2,3], 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enumerator:

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  [1, 2, 3].inject (3) do |sum, n|
     y << sum + n
     sum + n
  end
end

enum.take([1,2,3].size) #=> [4, 6, 9]
```

Obviously you can wrap this up nicely in a method, but I'll leave that for you to do. Also don't think there's much wrong with your attempt, works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(arr, initial_value)
  arr.each_with_object([initial_value]) { |e,a| a << e+a[-1] }.drop 1
end

arr = [1,2,3]
initial_value = 4

doit(arr, initial_value)
  #=> [5, 7, 10]
```

This lends itself to being generalized.

```
def gen_doit(arr, initial_value, op)
  arr.each_with_object([initial_value]) { |e,a| a << a[-1].send(op,e) }.drop 1
end

gen_doit(arr, initial_value, :+)  #=> [5,7,10]
gen_doit(arr, initial_value, '-') #=> [3, 1, -2] 
gen_doit(arr, initial_value, :*)  #=> [4, 8, 24] 
gen_doit(arr, initial_value, '/') #=> [4, 2, 0] 
gen_doit(arr, initial_value, :**) #=> [4, 16, 4096]
gen_doit(arr, initial_value, '%') #=> [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Also, one might use a codeblock parameter: `def gen_doit(arr, initial_value) ; arr.each_with_object([initial_value]) { |e,a| a << yield(e, a[-1]) }.drop 1 ; end` ⇒ `gen_doit([1,2,3], 4) do |e, a| e + a end`  (or `gen_doit([1,2,3], 4, &:+)`)⇒ `#=> [5, 7, 10]`.